# Java 2d game issue

Tags: java, sprite, game-engine

I've created 2d java game with Slick2d library. This game is about WHITE(player) and RED (enemy) squares. The red one is chasing the white one on 640 x 640 gameboard and your mission is to run from the red one, moving around... Very simple.

My problem is, I have only defined 1 enemy chaser and I want to be chased by more. I want it to be like when I press "N" key, the another one red square appears and starts to chase me. I press "N" key again, so from now 3 red squares are chasing me. I want it to be something like I can press "N" infinity times and still more red squares appear.

Lets say I got void init, render, update. I didn't copy whole code (because it looks messy), but that is not the point because the game is working correctly.

```
public class PlayTestState extends BasicGameState {

// moving method stands for moving WHITE square (player moves it with arrows)
void moving(Input input) {
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
            // human = movingUp;
            mainPositionY -= .5f;

            if (mainPositionY < 32) {
                mainPositionY += .5f;
            }
        }
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
            // human = movingUp;
            mainPositionY += .5f;

            if (mainPositionY > 576) {
                mainPositionY -= .5f;
            }
        }
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
            // human = movingUp;
            mainPositionX -= .5f;

            if (mainPositionX < 32) {
                mainPositionX += .5f;
            }

        }
        if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
            // human = movingUp;
            mainPositionX += .5f;

            if (mainPositionX > 576) {
                mainPositionX -= .5f;
            }
        }
    }


Image you, enemy;

double mainCharacterSpeed = 0.5;
double enemyCharacterSpeed = 0.3;

float mainPositionX = 320; // stands for white square (player) start position
float mainPositionY = 320;

float enemyPositionX = 320; // stands for red square (enemy - computer) start position
float enemyPositionY = 96;

    //that chase method stands for red square chasing after white one
     void chase() {  
        if (enemyPositionY < mainPositionY)
            enemyPositionY += enemyCharacterSpeed;
        if (enemyPositionX > mainPositionX)
            enemyPositionX -= enemyCharacterSpeed;
        if (enemyPositionX < mainPositionX)
            enemyPositionX += enemyCharacterSpeed;
        if (enemyPositionY > mainPositionY)
            enemyPositionY -= enemyCharacterSpeed;
    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
                throws SlickException {


    you = new Image("res/draws/mainCharacter.png");
    enemy = new Image ("res/draws/enemyCharacter.png");
        }
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)
            throws SlickException {
you.draw(mainPositionX, mainPositionY);
        enemy.draw(enemyPositionX, enemyPositionY);
}
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
            throws SlickException {
Input input = gc.getInput();
moving(input);
 }
}
}
```

Any ideas how to do it?
Do I have to make some kind of ArrayList with enemy objects?

Comment: yes. something like if(input == "N") enemies.add(new Enemy()); Then update the whole list.

Comment: But if 1 enemy has some position parameters defined by enemyPositionX, enemyPositionY, then the other one gona have the same parameters, which will make him at the same position :/

Comment: Take a *closer* look at what Bene hinted; you need to *remove* the enemy position from the GameState, create a class Enemy and have GameState hold a *List* of Enemy instances.

Comment: I was thinkin the same, but kinda no idea how to connect these playState class with enemyClass. I thought maybe i can make it this way :{

Comment: im rly rly beginner at this kind of things :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common hurdle for beginners, slicing state in a sensible and flexible way. Whenever you need potentially more than one instance of something (like enemy here), you *cannot* tie the state of such an entity directly to the game state in a one-to-one relationship.

So first, factor out the enemy state and make it a separate class Enemy:

```
class Enemy {
    float x, y;
    Image image = ...

    // creates an enemy
    public Enemy(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // draws this enemy
    public void render(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And change GameState to hold more than one enemy, by replacing the enemyPositionX and enemyPositionY with:

```
class GameState {
    List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now the list will be initially empty, so you need to explicitly create an enemy, e.g. in the GameState's init() method:

```
enemies.add(new Enemy(320, 96));
```

Now make your render() method deal with the list of enemies, so alter your GameState's render() to delegate rendering of the enemy to its render method:

```
public void render(...) {
    you.draw(...);
    for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
        enemy.render(...);
    }
}
```

Now adding a new enemy is as simple as it was creating the initial enemy: `enemies.add(new Enemey(x, y))`.

You still want the enemies to chase the *player*, so the chase method goes into the enemy class as well. And it receives as parameter the location to chase:

```
 public void chase(float mainPositionX, float mainPositionY) {
     ...
 }
```

And you call it from the GameState in a loop, just like you do in render():

```
 for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
     enemy.chase(mainPositionX, mainPositionY);
 }
```

The *key* point is to put states in *separate objects* and manage their *relationships*. There is a lot of potential for simplification left (e.g. using inheritance to take advantage of the common aspects between Player and Enemy). I leave that for you to explore.